# How to play video at correct frame rate?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video recorded with fps 15 and when I reply it with mplayer it is replayed way too fast (it has a timestamp in it so you can see it is at least double as fast as normal speed). Even when I specify `-fps 15` the video still runs too fast.

Is there a command line option for mplayer to have the video played at normal speed?

```
ffmpeg -i video.ts
```

shows:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'hexcam02-20231110-130000.ts':
  Duration: 00:10:00.00, start: 0.133333, bitrate: 1753 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 2023-11-10 13:00:00.001
      service_provider: gvos-6.0
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
```